# How to provide multiple account credentials to `cdk bootstrap`?

Tags: aws-cdk

We are developing a multi-account CDK app, and performing continuous deployment on CodeBuild. We are aware of [CDK authentication issues](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1656) so we use `$ aws sts assume-role` and set environment variables to switch AWS accounts during `$ cdk deploy`. This way works fine with `$ cdk deploy`, but `$ cdk bootstrap` is not.  `$ cdk bootstrap` tries to bootstrap every account and requires multiple account credentials.  Is there any simple way to provide multiple account credentials for `$ cdk bootstrap`? (implementing custom plugin is not "simple"...) Otherwise, is there any way to bootstrap a single account?

```
# with 111111111111 account credential
$ cdk bootstrap --execute=false
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://111111111111/us-east-1...
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://222222222222/us-east-1...
 ❌  Environment aws://222222222222/us-east-1 failed bootstrapping: Error: Need to perform AWS calls for account 222222222222, but no credentials found. Tried: default credentials.
```

```js
import "source-map-support/register";
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";
import * as sns from "@aws-cdk/aws-sns";

class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    new sns.Topic(this, sns.Topic.name);
  }
}

const app = new cdk.App();
new MyStack(app, "MyStack1", {
  env: { account: "111111111111", region: "us-east-1" }
});
new MyStack(app, "MyStack2", {
  env: { account: "222222222222", region: "us-east-1" }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass environment as an argument to `cdk bootstrap` command.

> cdk bootstrap [ENVIRONMENTS..]

```
cdk bootstrap aws://111111111111/us-east-1
```

So in your case, you have to switch accounts before running each bootstrap command, exactly as you do for deployments.

```
aws sts assume-role ...

ACCOUNT=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)
REGION=$(aws configure get region)

cdk bootstrap aws://$ACCOUNT/$REGION
```